# How to fill text with particles using p5js

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, p5.js

I want to fill a text with particles like this

[image]

I tried to do this using p5.js but I am stuck where the particles are only appearing on the edges. Any idea to accomplish this rather than having it on the edges?

Here is my attempt.
Thanks a ton in advance :)

SteeringDemo.html

```
<body>
<script>
var font;
var vehicles=[];
var x=1360;
var y=400;
function preload() {
    font=loadFont('Poppins-Medium.ttf')
}
function setup() {
    var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var width = canvasDiv.offsetWidth;
    var sketchCanvas = createCanvas(width,450);
    console.log(sketchCanvas);
    sketchCanvas.parent("canvas");
    background('#fff');

    var points=font.textToPoints('B',x/3,y/2,240);
    console.log(points);
    for(i=0;i<points.length;i++){
        var pt=points[i];
        var vehicle = new Vehicle(pt.x, pt.y);
        vehicles.push(vehicle);
    }
}
function draw() {
    background('#fff');
    for(var i=0; i< vehicles.length;i++){
        var v=vehicles[i];
        v.behaviors();
        v.update();
        v.show();
    }
}
</script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div id="canvas"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Vehicle.js

```
function Vehicle(x,y) {
  this.pos= createVector(random(width),random(height));
  this.target=createVector(x,y);
  this.vel= p5.Vector.random2D();
  this.acc= createVector();
  this.radius=8;
  this.maxspeed=10;
  this.maxForce=1;
}
Vehicle.prototype.behaviors=function () {
  var arrive=this.arrive(this.target);
  var mouse= createVector(mouseX,mouseY);
  var flee=this.flee(mouse);
  arrive.mult(1);
  flee.mult(5);
  this.applyForce(arrive);
  this.applyForce(flee);
}
Vehicle.prototype.applyForce =function (f) {
  this.acc.add(f);
}
Vehicle.prototype.update=function () {
  this.pos.add(this.vel);
  this.vel.add(this.acc);
  this.acc.mult(0);
}
Vehicle.prototype.show=function () {
  stroke('#0097a7');
  strokeWeight(4);
  point(this.pos.x,this.pos.y);
}
Vehicle.prototype.arrive= function (target) {
  var desired=p5.Vector.sub(target,this.pos);
  var d=desired.mag();
  var speed=this.maxspeed;
  if(d < 100) {
    speed=map(d,0,100,0,this.maxspeed)
  }
  desired.setMag(speed);
  var steer=p5.Vector.sub(desired,this.vel);
  steer.limit(this.maxForce);
  return steer;
}

Vehicle.prototype.flee= function (target) {
  var desired=p5.Vector.sub(target,this.pos);
  var d= desired.mag();
  if(d <50) {
    desired.setMag(this.maxspeed);
    desired.mult(-1);
    var steer=p5.Vector.sub(desired,this.vel);
    steer.limit(this.maxForce);
    return steer;
  } else {
    return createVector(0,0);
  }
 }
```

Comment: [Craig reynold's](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/) steering algorithms?

Comment: yeah steering algorithm.

Comment: anyone here please to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you could but, you don't have to use p5<sub>*</sub>js to achieve that animation. Fortunately, I've came across a javascript library called [**Particle Slider**](http://particleslider.com/)
and as it turns out, [*yalantis*](https://yalantis.com/) also using the same library for their animation.

Here is how you could accomplish such animation using that library.

```js
let init = () => {
    PS.renderText({
        text: 'B',
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        fontSize: 200,
        fontColor: '#00E2FA',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    });
    var myPS = new ParticleSlider({
        ptlGap: 3,
        ptlSize: 1,
        mouseForce: 70
    });
    window.onresize = () => {
        myPS.width = window.innerWidth;
        myPS.height = window.innerHeight;
    }
}
window.onload = init;
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://istack.000webhostapp.com/PS.js"></script>
<!-- DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING AFTER THIS LINE -->
<div class="slides">
    <div class="slide"> </div>
</div>
<canvas class="draw"></canvas>
<!-- DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BEFORE THIS LINE -->
```

Yes! It's really that *easy* :)

also, checkout a [**demo on jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/p8Lq2d16/)

*for future reference always refer to the* [*official documentation*](http://particleslider.com/documentation/api)

Comment: you know bro you are savior thanks thanks and thanks a ton!! :D :)

Comment: @BhavikBamania BTW, please edit the question to a specific problem (probably, to accommodate this answer) or the question might get deleted :)

Comment: yes I have edited have a look if you found something irrelevant then feel free to edit it. :)

Comment: For anyone interested how to do it without 3rdparty code http://stackoverflow.com/a/43414772/3877726 no point letting it go to waste.

Comment: hey is it possible to render color of image in data-src in particles if yes then how??

Comment: @BhavikBamania um.. yes possible. but please refrain from asking additional (new) questions in the comment section, rather ask an actual question with sufficient details :)

Comment: @moaois posted have a look :)