# how to fill particles inside rectangle?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm looking to draw a rectangle basically text but just for clearing insight I'm working it with rectangle with small particles inside rectangle the basic I idea I got from https://yalantis.com/ but in my attempt I'm stuck here with solid filled rectangle with a color I have specified for particles. Please help me.. :)

Thanks here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Off Screen Canvas</title>
<script>
    function createOffscreenCanvas() {
        var offScreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        offScreenCanvas.width = '1360';
        offScreenCanvas.height = '400';
        var context = offScreenCanvas.getContext("2d");
        var W=200;
        var H=200;
        particleCount = 200;
        particles = []; //this is an array which will hold our particles Object/Class
        function Particle() {
            this.x = Math.random() * W;
            this.y = Math.random() * H;
            this.direction ={"x": -1 + Math.random()*2, "y": -1 + Math.random()*2};
            this.vx = 2 * Math.random() + 4 ;
            this.vy = 2 * Math.random() + 4;
            this.radius = .9 * Math.random() + 1;
            this.move = function(){
                this.x += this.vx * this.direction.x;
                this.y += this.vy * this.direction.y;
            };
            this.changeDirection = function(axis){
                this.direction[axis] *= -1;
            };
            this.draw = function() {
                context.beginPath();
                context.fillStyle = "#0097a7";
                context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
                context.fill();
            };
            this.boundaryCheck = function(){
                if(this.x >= W){
                    this.x = W;
                    this.changeDirection("x");
                }
                else if(this.x <= 0){
                    this.x = 0;
                    this.changeDirection("x");
                }
                if(this.y >= H){
                    this.y = H;
                    this.changeDirection("y");
                }
                else if(this.y <= 0){
                    this.y = 0;
                    this.changeDirection("y");
                }
            };
        }
        function createParticles(){
            for (var i = particleCount-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                p = new Particle();
                particles.push(p);
            }
        }// end createParticles
        function drawParticles(){
            for (var i = particleCount-1; i >= 0; i--){
                p = particles[i];
                p.draw();
            }
        } //end drawParticles

        function updateParticles(){
            for(var i = particles.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
                p = particles[i];
                p.move();
                p.boundaryCheck();

            }
        }//end updateParticle
        createParticles();
        var part=drawParticles();
        context.fillStyle=part;
        context.fillRect(W-190, H-190, W, H);
        context.fill();
        return offScreenCanvas;
    }
    function copyToOnScreen(offScreenCanvas) {
        var onScreenContext=document.getElementById('onScreen').getContext('2d');
        var offScreenContext = offScreenCanvas.getContext('2d');
        var image=offScreenContext.getImageData(10,10,200,200);
        onScreenContext.putImageData(image,offScreenCanvas.width/2,offScreenCanvas.height/4);
    }

    function main() {
        copyToOnScreen(createOffscreenCanvas());
    }
</script>
<style>
    canvas {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body onload="main()"> 
<canvas id="onScreen" width="1360" height="400"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: anyone here to help ??

Comment: hello there!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well after all the attempts like hell I finally got my answer thanks to [moáois](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7750640/mo%C3%A1ois) answer to my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393966/how-to-fill-text-with-particles-using-p5js) using particle slider. here is the code. Thanks everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

I see you have not found what you are looking for yet. Below is something quick to get you on your way. There is a whole range of stuff being used from canvas,mouse,particles, etc most of which is without comments. There is no load balancing or compliance testing and because it uses babel to be compatible with IE11 I have no clue how it runs on those browsers.

I will add to this answer some other time but for now I am a little over it.

```js
const textList = ["1","2","3","Testing","text","to","particles"];
var textPos = 0;
function createParticles(text){
    createTextMap(
        text,  // text to display
        40,    // font size
        "Arial",  // font
        {  // style fot rendering font
            fillStyle : "#6AF",
            strokeStyle : "#F80",
            lineWidth : 2,
            lineJoin : "round",
        },{  // bounding box to find a best fit for
            top : 0,
            left : 0,
            width : canvas.width,
            height : canvas.height,
        }
    )
}
// This function starts the animations
var started = false;
function startIt(){
    started = true;
    const next = ()=>{
        var text = textList[(textPos++ ) % textList.length];
        particles.mouseFX.dist = canvas.height  / 8;
        createParticles(text);
        setTimeout(moveOut,text.length * 100 + 3000);
    }
    const moveOut = ()=>{
        particles.moveOut();
        setTimeout(next,2000);
    }
    setTimeout(next,0);
}


function setStyle(ctx,style){
    Object.keys(style).forEach(key => ctx[key] = style[key]);
}

// the following function create the particles from text using a canvas
// the canvas used is dsplayed on the main canvas top left fro referance.
var tCan = createImage(100, 100); // canvas used to draw text
function createTextMap(text,size,font,style,fit){
    // function to conver to colour hex value
    const hex = (v)=> (v < 16 ? "0" : "") + v.toString(16);
    // set up font so we can find the size.
    tCan.ctx.font = size + "px " + font;
    // get size of text
    var width = Math.ceil(tCan.ctx.measureText(text).width + size);
    // resize the canvas to fit the text
    tCan.width = width;
    tCan.height = Math.ceil(size *1.2);
    // c is alias for context
    var c = tCan.ctx;
    // set up font 
    c.font = size + "px " + font;
    c.textAlign = "center";
    c.textBaseline = "middle";
    // set style
    setStyle(c,style);
    // only do stroke and fill if they are set in styles object
    if(style.strokeStyle){
        c.strokeText(text, width / 2, tCan.height / 2);
    }
    if(style.fillStyle){
        c.fillText(text, width / 2, tCan.height/ 2);
    }
    // prep the particles
    particles.empty();
    // get the pixel data
    var data = c.getImageData(0,0,width,tCan.height).data;
    var x,y,ind,rgb,a;
    // find pixels with alpha > 128
    for(y = 0; y < tCan.height; y += 1){
        for(x = 0; x < width; x += 1){
            ind = (y * width + x) << 2;  // << 2 is equiv to * 4
            if(data[ind + 3] > 128){  // is alpha above half
                rgb = `#${hex(data[ind ++])}${hex(data[ind ++])}${hex(data[ind ++])}`;
                // add the particle
                particles.add(Vec(x, y), Vec(x, y), rgb);
            }
        }
    }
    // scale the particles to fit bounding box
    var scale = Math.min(fit.width / width, fit.height / tCan.height);
    particles.each(p=>{
        p.home.x = ((fit.left + fit.width) / 2) + (p.home.x - (width / 2)) * scale;
        p.home.y = ((fit.top + fit.height) / 2) + (p.home.y - (tCan.height / 2)) * scale;

    })
        .findCenter() // get center used to move particles on and off of screen
        .moveOffscreen()  // moves particles off the screen
        .moveIn();        // set the particles to move into view.

}
// vector object a quick copy from other code.
function Vec(x,y){  // because I dont like typing in new
    return new _Vec(x,y);
}
function _Vec(x = 0,y = 0){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    return this;
}
_Vec.prototype = {
    setAs(vec){
        this.x = vec.x;
        this.y = vec.y;
    },
    toString(){
        return `vec : { x : ${this.x}, y : ${this.y} );`
    }
}

// basic particle
const particle = {
    pos : null,
    delta : null,
    home : null,
    col : "black",
}
// array of particles
const particles = {
    items : [], // actual array of particles
    mouseFX : {  // mouse FX
        power : 20,
        dist : 100,
        curve : 3, // polynomial power
        on : true,
    },
    fx : {
        speed : 0.4,
        drag : 0.15,
        size : 4,
        jiggle : 8,
    },
    // direction 1 move in -1 move out
    direction : 1,
    moveOut(){this.direction = -1; return this},
    moveIn(){this.direction = 1; return this},
    length : 0, // Dont touch this from outside particles.
    each(callback){ // custom iteration 
        for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
            callback(this.items[i],i);
        }
        return this;
    },
    empty(){ // empty but dont dereference
        this.length = 0;
        return this;
    },
    deRef(){  // call to clear memory
        this.items.length = 0;
        this.length = 0;
    },
    add(pos,home,col){  // adds a particle
        var p;
        if(this.length < this.items.length){
            p = this.items[this.length++];
           // p.pos.setAs(pos);
            p.home.setAs(home);
            p.delta.x = 0;
            p.delta.y = 0;
            p.col = col;
        }else{
            this.items.push(
                Object.assign(
                    {},
                    particle,
                    {
                        pos,
                        home,
                        col,
                        delta : Vec()
                    }
                )
            );
            this.length = this.items.length
        }
        return this;
    },
    draw(){ // draws all
        var p, size, sizeh;
        sizeh = (size = this.fx.size) / 2;
        for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
            p = this.items[i];
            ctx.fillStyle = p.col;
            ctx.fillRect(p.pos.x - sizeh, p.pos.y - sizeh, size, size);
        }
    },
    update(){ // update all particles
        var p,x,y,d;
        var mP = this.mouseFX.power;
        var mD = this.mouseFX.dist;
        var mC = this.mouseFX.curve;
        var fxJ = this.fx.jiggle;
        var fxD = this.fx.drag;
        var fxS = this.fx.speed;

        for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
            p = this.items[i];
            p.delta.x += (p.home.x - p.pos.x ) * fxS + (Math.random() - 0.5) * fxJ;
            p.delta.y += (p.home.y - p.pos.y ) * fxS + (Math.random() - 0.5) * fxJ;
            p.delta.x *= fxD;
            p.delta.y *= fxD;
            p.pos.x += p.delta.x * this.direction;
            p.pos.y += p.delta.y * this.direction;
            if(this.mouseFX.on){
                x = p.pos.x - mouse.x;
                y = p.pos.y - mouse.y;
                d = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
                if(d < mD){
                    x /= d;
                    y /= d;
                    d /= mD;
                    d = (1-Math.pow(d,mC)) * mP;
                    p.pos.x += x * d;
                    p.pos.y += y * d;        
                }
            }
        }
        return this;
    },
    findCenter(){  // find the center of particles maybe could do without
        var x,y;
        y = x = 0;
        this.each(p => {
            x += p.home.x;
            y += p.home.y;
        });
        this.center = Vec(x / this.length, y / this.length);
        return this;
    },
    moveOffscreen(){  // move start pos offscreen
        var dist,x,y;
        dist = Math.sqrt(this.center.x * this.center.x + this.center.y * this.center.y);
        
        this.each(p => {
            var d;
            x = p.home.x - this.center.x;
            y = p.home.y - this.center.y;
            d =  Math.max(0.0001,Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y)); // max to make sure no zeros
            p.pos.x = p.home.x + (x / d)  * dist;
            p.pos.y = p.home.y + (y / d)  * dist;
        });
        return this;
    },
}
function onResize(){  // called from boilerplate
    if(!started){
        startIt();
    }
}

/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js begin **/
// the following globals are available
// w, h, cw, ch,  width height centerWidth centerHeight of canvas
// canvas, ctx, mouse, globalTime  

//MAIN animation loop
function display() { // call once per frame
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // reset alpha
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    if(tCan){
       // ctx.drawImage(tCan,0,0);
    }
    particles.update();
    particles.draw();
    
}




/******************************************************************************
 The code from here down is generic full page mouse and canvas boiler plate 
 code. As I do many examples which all require the same mouse and canvas 
 functionality I have created this code to keep a consistent interface. The
 Code may or may not be part of the answer.
 This code may or may not have ES6 only sections so will require a transpiler
 such as babel.js to run on legacy browsers.
 *****************************************************************************/
// V2.0 ES6 version for Stackoverflow and Groover QuickRun 
var w, h, cw, ch, canvas, ctx, mouse, globalTime = 0;
// You can declare onResize (Note the capital R) as a callback that is also
// called once at start up. Warning on first call canvas may not be at full
// size. 
;(function(){
    const RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME = 100;
    var resizeTimeoutHandle;
    var firstRun = true;
    function createCanvas () {
        var c,cs;
        cs = (c = document.createElement("canvas")).style;
        cs.position = "absolute";
        cs.top = cs.left = "0px";
        cs.zIndex = 1000;
        document.body.appendChild(c);
        return c;
    }
    function resizeCanvas () {
        if (canvas === undefined) { canvas = createCanvas() }
        canvas.width = innerWidth;
        canvas.height = innerHeight;
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        if (typeof setGlobals === "function") { setGlobals() }
        if (typeof onResize === "function") {
            clearTimeout(resizeTimeoutHandle);
            if (firstRun) { onResize() }
            else { resizeTimeoutHandle = setTimeout(onResize, RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME) }
            firstRun = false;
        }
    }
    function setGlobals () {
        cw = (w = canvas.width) / 2;
        ch = (h = canvas.height) / 2;
    }
    mouse = (function () {
        function preventDefault(e) { e.preventDefault() }
        var m; // alias for mouse
        var mouse = {
            x : 0, y : 0, w : 0, // mouse position and wheel
            alt : false, shift : false, ctrl : false, // mouse modifiers 
            buttonRaw : 0,
            over : false,                        // true if mouse over the element
            buttonOnMasks : [0b1, 0b10, 0b100],  // mouse button on masks
            buttonOffMasks : [0b110, 0b101, 0b011], // mouse button off masks
            active : false,
            bounds : null,
            eventNames : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(","),
            event(e) {
                var t = e.type;
                m.bounds = m.element.getBoundingClientRect();
                m.x = e.pageX - m.bounds.left - scrollX;
                m.y = e.pageY - m.bounds.top - scrollY;
                m.alt = e.altKey;
                m.shift = e.shiftKey;
                m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
                if (t === "mousedown") { m.buttonRaw |= m.buttonOnMasks[e.which - 1] }
                else if (t === "mouseup") { m.buttonRaw &= m.buttonOffMasks[e.which - 1] }
                else if (t === "mouseout") { m.over = false }
                else if (t === "mouseover") { m.over = true }
                else if (t === "mousewheel") {m.w = e.wheelDelta }
                else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") { m.w = -e.detail }
                if (m.callbacks) { m.callbacks.forEach(c => c(e)) }
                if ((m.buttonRaw & 2) && m.crashRecover !== null) {
                    if (typeof m.crashRecover === "function") { setTimeout(m.crashRecover, 0) }
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            },
            addCallback(callback) {
                if (typeof callback === "function") {
                    if (m.callbacks === undefined) {  m.callbacks = [callback] }
                    else { m.callbacks.push(callback) }
                }
            },
            start(element) {
                if (m.element !== undefined) { m.remove() }
                m.element = element === undefined ? document : element;
                m.eventNames.forEach(name =>  document.addEventListener(name, mouse.event) );
                document.addEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault, false);
                m.active = true;
            },
            remove() {
                if (m.element !== undefined) {
                    m.eventNames.forEach(name => document.removeEventListener(name, mouse.event) );
                    document.removeEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault);
                    m.element = m.callbacks = undefined;
                    m.active = false;
                }
            }
        }
        m = mouse;
        return mouse;
    })();
    function done() { // Clean up. Used where the IDE is on the same page.
        window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas)
        mouse.remove();
        document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        canvas = ctx = mouse = undefined;
    }
    function update(timer) { // Main update loop
        if(ctx === undefined){ return }
        globalTime = timer;
        display();           // call demo code
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        canvas = createCanvas(); 
        mouse.start(canvas, true);
        resizeCanvas();
        if(typeof Groover !== "undefined" && Groover.ide){ mouse.crashRecover = done }; // Requires Ace.js and GrooverDev.js. Prevents
        window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    },0);
})();
/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js end **/
/** CreateImage.js begin **/
// creates a blank image with 2d context
function createImage(w,h){var i=document.createElement("canvas");i.width=w;i.height=h;i.ctx=i.getContext("2d");return i;}
/** CreateImage.js end **/
```

```css
canvas {
   background : black;
}
```